# How to use social_stream gem in rails 4.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using rails 4.2.0. Now I want to make a social networking site using ruby on rails. I want to use social_stream gem, but unable to add. Is it not acceptable in rails 4.2.0 ? Or any other way to implement social networking using rails?

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails"

Comment: The gem wasn't updated for two years, so I don't think that it's compatible with Rails 4.2. You can try to grab the source from Github and update the dependencies, then build the gem again.